# Disable Eclipse warnings programatically in single Maven module generating sources?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a multi-module Maven project, in which one module is responsible for invoking OpenAPI generator on our openapi.yaml file resulting in a lot of Java sources under `target/` which is then compiled into an artifact used in the rest of the project.   This works well.

Unfortunately these generated sources trigger quite a few warnings in Eclipse 2022-03 after importing the Maven project.   I would therefore like to know if it is possible to have m2e adjust a few compiler settings for this module only, when importing the project, or if my only option is to set this in Eclipse and then carefully commit the resulting configuration files?

Our goal is to have as near a "pure Maven" solution as possible.  Can this be done?

Comment: Can you tell which `trigger quite a few warnings in ` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Things like "unused import" and "unused variable" - which is perfectly fair, they just add noise.

Comment: The simplest solution is to solve those warnings because such things are a hint about not well maintained code... And no there is no programmatic way to turn such warnings off in Maven for Eclipse, because that's a warnings of Eclipse. The other question is: How have you configured the openapi tools to generate the code? So in such case a full pom file would help here..

Comment: The generated code comes from the "spring" generator, which in turn uses a rather complex moustache template to generate the sources (as in: a rather deep dive to fix upstream which I'd rather avoid if at all possible).   It is still an interesting problem though if the eclipse compiler can be configured more detailed than just the source level. Perhaps I should reword in a new question.